# can't open python packages installed through brew

Tags: python, homebrew

I installed portaudio module through brew with the following command :

`brew install portaudio`

and it got installed successfully

But the problem is that while writing a program in my text editor (Sublime Text) I am able to import modules that were imported using pip only, not brew .

Code in text editor : `import portaudio`

Error : `ImportError: No module named portaudio`

portaudio cannot get installed using pip too. Following message came for the line `pip install portaudio`

`Collecting portaudio`

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement portaudio (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for portaudio`

whatr should i do?

Answer (score 0):

[The `portaudio` library that Homebrew installs](http://www.portaudio.com) appears to be a C and C++ library only, not Python.

Comment: Iam trying to install dependencies of the following project, written in python- [dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md)